# How can I safely access each element in a Haskell list?

Tags: haskell, recursion, iteration

I am new to Haskell and the syntax has been giving me a bit of trouble, especially in understanding how to iterate. I am creating a method what will process a string and return a list of tuples containing each letter and their number of occurences.

The tuples do reappear with duplicate letters so a list like "abba" should return [('a',2), ('b',2), ('b',2), ('a',2)]

```
counting_letters :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a,Int)]
counting_letters [] = []
counting_letters list
   | length list == 0 = []
   | otherwise = [(x,c) | x <- [head list], let c = (length.filter(==x)) list]
```

Right now, the only cases that work as expected are the empty list and single element lists such as "a". I understand that this only points to the head but when I attempted to use `[head list .. last list]` it gave me an error that it could not deduce (Enum a). How can I safely access each element in a list?

Comment: 1. Do not use `head`, instead pattern match on the string. (i.e. you might change `counting_letters list` into `counting_letters (hd : tl)` and use `hd` for head, `tl` for tail)
Also, `length list == 0` only happens with empty list, which is covered in the case above.

Comment: 2. It is, in fact, not a syntax. In haskell, we usually do not iterate. Instead, we work with recursions. By the way, you need to keep a reference to the entire list to count properly.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you desire is simply

```
counting_letters :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a,Int)]
counting_letters list = [(x,c) | x <- list, let c = (length.filter(==x)) list]
```

without any special cases.

Comment: So x <- list refers to every element in the list?

Comment: Yes, `(x, c)` and any guards (like `let c = ...`) are evaluated for each value `x` that can be found in `list`.